# JSF Prime Faces, Spring 3, Hibernate 4 - org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, jsf, hibernate-4.x

I see many posts about this topic. After 2 days of reading, I am at my wits end

It seems pretty simple. The session is closed, then JSF goes to render the lazy loaded collection and is unable to use the session.

What am I missing?  I am going crazy

**web.xml**

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-  class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
      </init-param>
  </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" />
                <property name="username" value="username" />
                <property name="password" value="password" />
   </bean> 
           <bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="configLocation">
                <value>/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

**Service Layer**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<Order> findAll() {
    return orderDAO.findAll();
}
```

**OrderDAO.java**

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(getReferenceClass()).list();
}
```

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name="orders"   
)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Order implements Serializable, Data {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PrimaryKeyword> primKeywords;

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void addToPrimKeywords(PrimaryKeyword primKeyword) {
        if (primKeywords == null) {
            primKeywords = new ArrayList<PrimaryKeyword>();
        }
        this.primKeywords.add(primKeyword);
    }

    public List<PrimaryKeyword> getPrimKeywords() {
        return primKeywords;
    }
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
    INFO: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.ardor.data.Order.primKeywords, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.ardor.data.Order.primKeywords, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:394)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:242)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.isRowAvailable(ListDataModel.java:109)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.setRowIndex(ListDataModel.java:184)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.setWrappedData(ListDataModel.java:219)
    at javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.<init>(ListDataModel.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:258)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:444)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:483)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.processDecodes(UIRepeat.java:755)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.process(UIData.java:322)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:305)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:267)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:231)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:252)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:928)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you post your `Order.java` and body of implementor's `findOrder()` method?

Comment: @n1k1ch I just edited the post to include that info. Anything else to take a look at? A 3rd day stuck on this is going to suck! :)

Comment: Is `FetchType.EAGER` appropriate for `primKeywords` in your case?

Comment: It turns out to be nothing to do with Spring and Hibernate but JSF lazy loading

<p:outputPanel deferred="true">

This was causing the problem. After the page was rendered and the session closed it goes back for more data and fails.

We were using this to make pages more responsive. Not sure of a work around